# Tutorial for C# web development

Tags: c#, odp.net

All,

I am looking for some good tutorial material to learn C# web development. Basically, I want to create a c# web form which would extract data from Oracle database and would give provision for the user to edit the data. I also want to have security for this website. I found some materials but it had SQL Server as the backend. I installed ODP.NET but don't know how to setup the security and add the web forms.

As, I am a new programmer for C#(have previous programming experience), I don't know where to start.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: What user permissions are you struggling with? DB user permissions, or permissions for users of the webform? The oracle .net data provider should work nearly 1:1 in place of the SQL Server ADO .NET Provider.

Comment: Which kind of programming experiences do you have? Which languages have you learned before you started with C#? Any of them object-oriented? That would help to understand a bit better your knowledge and knowing where to start.

Comment: I have experience in Oracle ERP which has OOPs and Java. I am struggling to setup a web application which has Oracle DB. I found few articles about setting up security based on SQL Server membership provider, but couldn't find a useful article to setup security with Oracle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For MS-SQL, you use System.Data.SqlClient

For Oracle, you can use the MS provided ADO.NET provider:
System.Data.OracleClient

You can get the connectionstring from connectionstrings.com

Oracle has it's own ADO.NET provider for .NET now, and you should use that one instead of System.Data.OracleClient, because MS is not maintaining the System.Data.OracleClient code anymore.

For the webforms part:
Don't use ASP.NET WebForms. Use ASP.NET MVC 3 + JQuery.

You have to manage permissions yourself.
It's best to do it in a http module.
Another way is to use System.DirectoryServices to access the ActiveDirectory.

Visual Studio has an integrated development testserver.
Use that one.
If you use AJAX, be aware that IIS7 runs in IntegratedMode, while the development server runs in Classic Mode. Which can get you errors caused by the web.config  file (sys not defined for example), or integrated security might not work, because in integratedMode, it runs as network-service user, and not as the current windows user.

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at any of the asp.Net [starter kits](http://www.asp.net/community/projects)?

For permissions to edit, I'm assuming you are referring to the website, take a look at the [ASP.Net Membership provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648345.aspx). If you are using Oracle this won't be as cut and dry as using SQL Server, but still doable.

Another option is you can role your own membership provider or a custom implementation.

To learn ASP.NET C#, there are plenty of tutorials articles on the web. For a book I recommend: [ASP.NET 4 Unleashed](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672331128)

**Update**

It appears that Oracle provides an [ASP.NET membership provider](http://download.oracle.com/docs/html/E10928_01/IntroOverview.htm).

Comment: Thanks. I will look into these tutorials. I basically wanted to know how should I setup the security. I read few articles which detailed using SQL server authentication and not Oracle. Hence, wanted to know how should I proceed.If you have any material which creates a basic web page using Oracle, please let me know.

Comment: Security is baked into the ASP.NET framework. It's a matter of leveraging the existing code. If the Oracle ASP.NET provider works as advertised then all you need to do is create tables in the database (this should be included with the provider) and configure the web site to use the Oracle provider. Then you'll need to code the web application to work as you like.

Comment: I would recommend against the usage of the built-in ASP.NET membership provider, it's crap in purity.

Comment: @Quandary I agree 100%.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this blog post, its a great start:

[ODP.NET C# Tutorial for Beginners Using Oracle and ASP.NET](http://muaca.blogspot.com/2011/08/odpnet-c-c-sharp-tutorial-for-beginner.html)